# Telegram Bot API. Не реагирует кнопка "принять" под сообщением

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть два бота. один бот пишет приветственное сообщение и запрашивает опыт у работника. Работник оставляет свою заявку, и эту заявку присылает второй бот в чат. Под этой заявкой есть кнопка принять, после нажатия на нее, первый бот должен отправить рабочему сообщение по типу "вы приняты на работу".

Но кнопка "принять" никак реагировать не хочет. Там что-то типа бесконечной загрузки, проблем с соединением нету, проверял `run&debug` - ошибок нету.

Вот сама "бесконечная загрузка кнопки":

[image: кнопка принять]

Вот код:

```
def process_application(message):
    user_profile_link = f"https://t.me/{message.from_user.username}"
    application_text = f"Профиль воркера: {user_profile_link}\nТекст заявки: {message.text}\nАйди воркера: {message.from_user.id}"
    bot_first.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваша заявка на рассмотрении, пожалуйста, дождитесь решения Администрации")
    bot_second.send_message(ADMIN_CHAT_ID, f"Новая заявка!✅️:\n{application_text}",
                            reply_markup=create_accept_button())

def create_accept_button():
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    accept_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Принять", callback_data="accept")
    keyboard.add(accept_button)
    return keyboard


def create_action_buttons():
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Каналы", callback_data="channels"))
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Инвайт", callback_data="invite"))
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Чат&Мануалы", callback_data="chat_manuals"))
    return keyboard


@bot_second.callback_query_handler
def accept_application(call):
    if call.data == "accept":
        bot_second.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ваша заявка была одобрена Администрацией!✅️", reply_markup=create_action_buttons())
```